# How to calculate Quantum Discord for two qubit system using Qutip?

Tags: qiskit, qutip, quantum-discord

Quantum discord of a bipartite system can be determined as:

$${D_A}({\rho _{AB}}) = I({\rho _{AB}}) - {J_A}({\rho _{AB}}),$$
The subscript of $A$ denotes that the measurement has been performed on the subsystem $A$.
The mutual information is defined as -
$$I({\rho _{AB}}) = S({\rho _A}) + S({\rho _B}) - S({\rho _{AB}}),$$

the classical correlation is defined as -

$${J_A}({\rho _{AB}}) = S({\rho _A}) - \mathop {\min }\limits_{\{ \Pi _I^A\} } \sum\limits_i {{p_i}S({\rho _{\left. B \right|i}})} ,$$
$$S({\rho _{\left. B \right|i}}) = {1 \over {{p_i}}}t{r_A}\left( {\Pi _i^A \otimes {I_B}} \right){\rho _{AB}}\left( {\Pi _i^A \otimes {I_B}} \right)$$

How does one calculate this quantity, computationally say, using Qutip or any other package/software, is there a code developed for this? Can anyone suggest an algorithm? Doing this analytically for any arbitrary density matrix, $\rho_{AB}$ is not feasible.

Comment: related github issue: https://github.com/qutip/qutip/issues/1450

Comment: Yes, but the thread provides no solution, and possibly no progress has happened since that conversation. I was hoping to find someone who might have done the computation and would have some advice.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/qutip/c/BvhlXRlEIPY you can ask Simon Cross here, for it. @Paranoid